# What are delimiters for in Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex

I have been gradually amping up my understanding/competency with RegExes. One thing I still have not understood is: what are delimiters for?

For example, I use [Regex101](https://regex101.com) a lot, and I noticed that for every flavour it has a list of delimiters for it on the left side of the regex field (the three vertical dots).

For **pcre** flavour it has `/`/`~`/`@`/`;`/`%` etc etc.

For **.NET** it has `"`/`""`/`""""` etc

But what are they for?

All my searches for this topic have turned up the subject of using a regular expression to delimit a string with a substring.

Comment: How would the language's compiler/interpreter know where the regex started and ended, otherwise?

Comment: There are no regex delimiters in .NET regexps. Quotes are used to define *string literals*. Regex delimiters are necessary to delimit `action/pattern/flags`

Comment: This is language-dependent. Some languages require delimiters, some don't.

Comment: @jasonharper, I thought thats what quoting/double quoting was for example in PowerShell `"hello world" -replace "^hello\s"` works fine.

Comment: @Barmar Can you give an example of a language that does not delimit its regex literals?

Comment: @Bergi Python doesn't have regexp literals. Neither do the C family.

Comment: @Barmar Well sure if you don't have literals, then you don't need to delimit them :-)

Comment: @Bergi Except for PHP....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delimiter's role is not to affect how the regex is interpreted in terms of pattern matching. Instead, it provides a way to separate the regex pattern from other parts of the code or terminal tool's interface, ensuring clarity and adhering to the conventions of the environment in which the regex is used.

When you're using regular expressions within various programming languages or platforms, there are often conventions or syntax requirements that you need to be aware of.

For example in PHP language that use delimiters, often there's an opportunity to append modifiers right after the closing delimiter. These modifiers can adjust the behaviour of the regex, such as making it case-insensitive.

```
preg_match('/[a-z]+/i', $string, $matches);
```

Regex101 provides a selection of delimiters for the flavor you choose because it wants to give you a representation of how you'd write the regex in the actual programming environment for that flavor.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the language.

Some languages have literals for regular expressions, and the delimiters are used to indicate where these literals begin and end (similar to the way quotes are used to delimit string literals). Languages like this include JavaScript, AWK, sed, and Perl. They use `/.../` as regular expression literlas; Perl and sed also allow you to use other delimiters to make things more convenient when the pattern includes literal `/` characters (as when matching pathnames, dates, and URLs).

Most other languages don't have a literal syntax for regular expressions, they just store them in strings. These generally don't require any special delimiters around the regexp, you just put quotes around the string.

In between these is PHP. It uses strings, but it also requires delimiters. This is because it puts the regexp flags in the string, and it uses the delimiters to separate the pattern from the flags. PHP doesn't have a fixed delimiter -- the first character of the string is the opening delimiter, and the match for this is the closing delimiter. Usually the closing delimiter is the same character as the opening delimiter (as when using `/.../`), but if the opening delimiter is the first character of a bracketing pair, the closing delimiter is the other member of the pair, so you can use `<...>` if you want.